# Pythonic way to find a minimum dictionary key with value in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value, minimum

I am coding an implementation of the Astar algorithm in Python and at some point I want to select the element in `open_set` that has the lowest `f_score value`:

```
# current is the node in open_set having the lowest f_score value
    current = min_f_score(open_set, f_score)
```

`open_set` is a list of tuples `(x, y)` that represent the coordinates of a point in 2D and `f_score` is a dictionary `{(x, y): score}` that assigns to each tuple `(x, y)` its `f_score` value.

My first implementation of `min_f_score` was the following:

```
def min_f_score(open_set, f_score):
    # First we initialize min_score_element and min_score
    min_score_element = open_set[0]
    min_score = f_score[open_set[0]]

    # Then we look for the element from f_score keys with the lowest value
    for element in open_set:
        if element in f_score.keys() and f_score[element] < min_score:
            min_score = f_score[element]
            min_score_element = element

    return min_score_element
```

It works fine but I was wondering if I could come up with some leaner, more pythonic code. After some research I came up with these two other implementations:

```
def min_f_score(open_set, f_score):   
    # We filter the elements from open_set and then find the min f_score value
    return min(filter(lambda k: k in open_set, f_score), key=(lambda k: f_score[k]))
```

and:

```
def min_f_score(open_set, f_score):   
    # We look for the min while assigning inf value to elements not in open_set
    return min(f_score, key=(lambda k: f_score[k] if k in open_set else float("inf")))
```

Both seem to work and give me the same results but are significantly slower than the first implementation.

I was wondering out of curiosity if there was any better way to implement `min_f_score`?

Edit: As suggested by @azro (thank you), I am adding an example of code to execute:

```
open_set = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (1, 4), (4, 1), (1, 5), (5, 0), (5, 1), (0, 6), (1, 6)]
f_score = {(0, 0): 486.0, (0, 1): 308.0, (1, 0): 308.0, (1, 1): 265.0, (0, 2): 265.0, (1, 2): 338.0, (0, 3): 284.0, (1, 3): 450.0, (2, 0): 265.0, (2, 1): 338.0, (2, 2): 629.0, (3, 0): 284.0, (3, 1): 450.0, (0, 4): 310.0, (1, 4): 550.0, (4, 0): 310.0, (4, 1): 564.0, (0, 5): 316.0, (1, 5): 588.0, (5, 0): 316.0, (5, 1): 606.0, (0, 6): 298.0, (1, 6): 534.0}
min_f_score(open_set, f_score)
```

Output: `(0, 6)`

Comment: That would be nice to provide a reproducible example with code that we can just paste and run, thanks

Comment: Your first implementation has the advantage that it is very readable and easy to understand

Comment: Um, why is open_set not a set?

Comment: @StefanPochmann That's a good question. At least it's a fine example why it's bad to have the type of the variable in the name.

Comment: In your example data, `open_set` is a subset of `f_score` and about half as big. Is it always a subset, and is half the size representative of your situation in general?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I used ```open_set``` because it was the name used in the description of the algorithm and I wanted to stick to it as closely as possible at least during my first implementation to make sure to not get confused, but that's a great remark!

Comment: @StefanPochmann ```open_set``` is a subset of ```f_score```, and is about 1/2 to 1/4 of the size of ```f_score```. I guess that also explains why my first implementation which only loops on the elements from ```open_set``` is faster than the others which loop on ```f_score```.

Comment: Where's the description from? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode)? That seems to make it a hash-set, at least its comment sounds like that. If it's always a subset, why do you do the `element in f_score.keys()` check? They also make fScore a "map with default", which in Python would be `collections.defaultdict`, which could help speed this up here as well.

Comment: The speed difference of looping over one or the other might have less to do with their sizes than with with the expensive `k in open_set` check when that's a list.

Answer (score 2):

#### V1

A version with `dict.get()` is much faster than your 2 `min()` versions (that were more than 10 times slower), but keeps being about 2 times slower

```
def min_f_score_d(open_set, f_score):
    inf = float("inf")
    return min(open_set, key=lambda k: f_score.get(k, inf))
```

#### V2

Suggested by [@stefan-pochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann), that one is sligthly slower than the classic iteration

```
def min_f_score(open_set, f_score):
    return min(f_score.keys() & open_set, key=f_score.get)
```

---

#### Note

```
if element in f_score        and f_score[element] < min_score:
# if faster than 
if element in f_score.keys() and f_score[element] < min_score:
```

---

#### Bench code

```py
from timeit import timeit

A = """
def min_f_score(open_set, f_score):
    min_score_element, min_score = open_set[0], f_score[open_set[0]]
    for element in open_set:
        if element in f_score and f_score[element] < min_score:
            min_score = f_score[element]
            min_score_element = element
    return min_score_element
"""

B = """
def min_f_score(open_set, f_score):
    inf = float("inf")
    return min(open_set, key=lambda k: f_score.get(k, inf))
"""

C = """
def min_f_score(open_set, f_score):
    return min(f_score.keys() & open_set, key=f_score.get)
"""

SETUP = """
from random import randrange
open_set = [(randrange(1000), randrange(1000)) for _ in range(1000)]
f_score = {pair: randrange(1000) for pair in open_set[:len(open_set) // 2]}
"""

NB = 20_000
print(timeit(setup=SETUP + A, stmt="min_f_score(open_set, f_score)", number=NB))  # ~2.7
print(timeit(setup=SETUP + B, stmt="min_f_score(open_set, f_score)", number=NB))  # ~4.8
print(timeit(setup=SETUP + C, stmt="min_f_score(open_set, f_score)", number=NB))  # ~3.1
```

Comment: Thanks. Disappointing that it's still slower than the original. Not sure the test data is appropriate, though. In the OP's example data, `open_set` is a subset of `f_score` and about half as big, while in your test data it's the other way around.

Comment: @StefanPochmann it seems that it is no really a subset as the OP added the checked that it was in it

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks for your suggestions and, those are really interesting!

Comment: @azro it should be a subset, I added the check to avoid unexpected cases/behaviors

Comment: @azro Also see our new comments under the question.

Comment: @pierre.db Might be *better* to have unexpected things that shouldn't happen raise an error instead of silently pretending nothing's wrong, as you then notice it and can do something about it.